# Evaluating variables from library

Tags: python, eval, robotframework

I have a python library (bar_variables) with following variables:

```
from bar_class import *

foo = bar_class()
```

Now in robot I have the following code:

```
Variables bar_variables.py

Setup
    ${variable1}=    Set Variable    ${foo}
    ${variable2}=    Set Variable    foo
    ${variable3}=    Evaluate    ${variable2}
```

variable 1 have the right object, while executing variable3 I get the following error:

```
Evaluating expression 'foo' failed: NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

If I try the same in python, it works:

```
from bar_variables import *

variable2 = 'foo'
variable3 = eval(variable2)
```

In python, variable3 has the right object while in robot it doesn't work

Robot version is:

```
>pybot --version
Robot Framework 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you import with the variable file don't exist in the context in which you run code with `Evaluate`. Even though you define `foo` in the variable file, the code run by `Evaluate` doesn't know anything about that variable.

What you describe in your question is exactly how robot is designed to work.

Comment: but, can I pass the context where variables exists in any way?

Comment: I don't think so. You may have an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: in the library there some diferentent variables which define possible physical topologies and from command line, using --variable TOPOLOGY:TOPOLOGY1 specify which topology is used, but topology variable will be an string with the name of the topology, not the topology object itself...